# return the extending class instance from an abstract method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a class that extends an abstract class.
does PHP allows access to the instance of the extending class from within the abstract methods?

something like:

```
abstract class Foo{
    protected function bar(){
        return $this;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    public function foo(){
        // this should hold Bar instance and not Foo's
        $barClassInstance = $this->bar();
    }
}
```

where $barClassInstance will hold the Bar class instance, instead of the abstract Foo instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying it out is worth a thousand stackoverflow questions

```
<?php

abstract class Foo{
    protected function bar(){
        echo 'Foo', PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($this);
        return $this;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    public function foo(){
        echo 'Bar', PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($this);
        // this should hold Bar instance and not Foo's
        $barClassInstance = $this->bar();
        var_dump($barClassInstance);
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->foo();
```

**output https://3v4l.org/b73bt**

```
Bar
object(Bar)#1 (0) {
}
Foo
object(Bar)#1 (0) {
}
object(Bar)#1 (0) {
}
```

`$this` is a reference to the instance regardless of which subclass it is actually an instance of. There is no `Foo` instance because `Foo` cannot be instantiated, it is abstract. Even if `Foo` were a concrete class, you wouldn't have a `Foo` `$this` and a `Bar` `$this` in the same object. You would only have `$this` pointing to the specific subclass that was created.